# no style for SharePoint:DateTimeControl when add bootstrap CSS

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, boot-strap

when i try to set a bootstrap style for my sharepoint page by adding css file, all SharePoint:DateTimeControl in my page loose their style and become something like this :
[image]

Comment: Bootstrap has some global rules which might make a mess in SharePoint, do you need to apply bootstrap to the whole page? We usually build bootstrap with `less` and that way target a specific parent selector

Comment: what do you mean by build bootstrap with less !

Comment: We use [less compiler](http://lesscss.org/) (and bower) to build bootstrap, then we can do something like `.some-app { @import "./bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less; }`, this way all bootstrap rules only apply within `.some-app` class. Of course rules for `body` and `html` etc. is lost, but beside that it works quite well.

Comment: can you give me some turorial about this ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know about any tutorial, but here my first hit on google: http://treyhunner.com/2015/02/creating-a-custom-bootstrap-build/

Comment: @eirikb how will that help? There'll actually be more code to write than currently. You'll have to individually style all elements. It will solve this issue, yes, but it'll be much more complex i think.

Comment: @uberz91 my example above is literally all the code you need, that is 72 characters, not very much code in my opinion, but it could be made smaller, perhaps down to 16 chars, less will handle the rest. And you don't need to import bootstrap.less, you could select the parts you need.

Comment: @eirikb oh ok. Havent read about this before so just had some doubts since it seems like a good idea and I'd want to implement it. But still, if you want to make the whole site responsive, you will have to use bootstrap globally. Also, if there are many different elements on the page, you will have to write code separately for the other elements right?

Comment: @uberz91 yes this approach will likely mess up responsivenes, but I'm not sure. But bootstrap has reset CSS and rules which messes up SharePoint, so mixing can be difficult. You don't need to apply this to every element, just wrap all your markup in <div class="some-app">...</div>

Comment: @eirikb thanks. Will have to try this and see. Learned something new today!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to add a limited set of bootstrap-styled controls (like a navbar, or a button group), you can create a custom bootstrap file [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and then remove all global styles (those applied to body, all paragraphs, all links etc.) and only keep the styling for the controls you want to add (usually styles applied to classes).
This way you'll get a small CSS file and you won't break SharePoint styles.

Has the drawbacks of being hard to maintain and takes a few minutes to look into the generated custom bootstrap.

Comment: Does this work? Can you remove `scaffolding.less` via their customizer? In my experience it's easier to wrap bootstrap even in manual building, since you need all the mixins and variables anyway (much less code to manage)